# Incorrect charset

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I have a problem with charset. On russian language I've saw symbol `�`

`<meta>` is **UTF-8** , in **DB** charset **utf8_general_ci** , take data from **DB** with **functions**

`substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 290) . '..'`

what's  the problem? what do you think?

Comment: What does the Content-Type response header say? It takes precedence over the `<meta charset>` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have Unicode characters and you are subtracting exactly in a wrong place and that letter cannot be rendered anymore.

Instead you should subtract by spaces, eg:

```
echo implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($sentence, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), 0, 50)); // for 50 words
```

or use [substr_unicode](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php):

```
function substr_unicode($str, $s, $l = null) {
    return join("", array_slice(
        preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY), $s, $l));
}
```